# Extract two elements of list and pass the rest recursively

Tags: recursion, f#, functional-programming, tail-recursion

I have a type def with 2 types and a list of the same type that may or may not be empty.

```
type Type1 = string
type Type2 = int
type Type3 = Sometype of Type1 * Type2 * Type3 list
```

I am trying to create a list of all the first two elements in the tuple, recursively passing along the last (a list of other type 3's), appending it to the list that I'm producing. Or at least that's what I'm trying. My function gives me an error:

```
let rec extSometypeInc d   =
   match d with
    | Sometype(n,i,[])         -> [(n,i)]
    | Sometype(n,i,r1::r2::rt) -> (n,i) :: extSometypeInc(r1,r2,rt)
    ;;
```

> error FS0001: This expression was expected to have type
>       Type3
>   but here has type
>       'a * 'b * 'c

Comment: please provide a clear, complete example on your problem - here we don't know anything about `Type1`, `Type2` and `extSometypeInc`... also the line where you get the error might help

Answer (score 4):

I'm not fully sure of your end goal here, but in terms of the unexpected result type you seem to have a syntax error.

```
| Sometype(n,i,r1::r2::rt) -> (n,i) :: extSometypeInc(r1,r2,rt)
```

Will pass a single tuple of three values to extSometypeInc as its first argument.

I believe you want:

```
| Sometype(n,i,r1::r2::rt) -> (n,i) :: (extSometypeInc r1 r2 rt)
```

which will pass it three arguments.

However, at this point you will find that the compiler will insist that Type1, Type2 and Type3 are all the same type, as lists in F# are constrained to hold values of a single type. You will also get a warning of an incomplete pattern match, as your function does not accommodate lists with an odd number of values.

Without knowing more about the problem you are attempting to serve, I'm not sure what the best solution to those problems would be.

Comment: Edited with clarifying descriptions.

Comment: Looking at your clarification, I'm not sure Type3 is representing what you were expecting. Can I suggest you give some example input and output to help us understand the problem?